# Parent child data

Tags: php, database

Hi I am working in a project where I have to save data with parent child relationship.

The data structure is like this:

```
flight_id     child_id      Flight_name 

1               1           E213    

2               2           E333

3               2           E444
```

Flight 1 has no `child_id` so it's parent id replaces it, flight 2 has two `child_id` so in each of `child_id` I have to put the parent id.

Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: Please clarify your question, as I am perfectly unable to see what are you trying to do here? You wish to have a code where you add the flights to the database? You want to set up relation-based database structure (it would then need two tables)?

Answer (score 1):

Parent-child relationships are usually modeled the other way around: the child belongs to a parent. Think about it, a child can only have one parent, that's easy to model; but a parent with many child ids is pretty hard to model.

Additionally you can use Nested Sets a.k.a. MPTT to make querying for children/parents easier.

See http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/ and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPTT.

Comment: I am saving data using Php query first i determined if data have child if it have then i simple insert query and then update it like this                                                                   $query = mysql_query("insert into test set flightname='$flight_code',childid='0'");
 $child_id = mysql_insert_id();
 $query=mysql_query("update test set flightname='$flight_code', childid='$child_id' where flightid='$child_id'");

Answer (score 0):

Normally you won't store all the child ID's, but the parent ID's:

```
CREATE TABLE `flight` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `parent` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `flight_name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    FOREIGN KEY (`parent`) REFERENCES `flight` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Your data would look like:

```
id     parent    flight_name 
1      NULL      E213    
2      NULL      E333
3      2         E444  
4      2         E555  
5      2         E666
```

Comment: yeah its like this sorry for misinterpretation. I mean exactly like this in my case parent is a foreign key too that have to be saved in another table

Comment: I don't know after inserting data for a parent that have one child how can i add data of same parent with 2nd child.

Comment: @mishi I've extended the example to let you get a feeling of how multiple children to one parent are stored. If you store the parents in a different table, they aren't really parent's as they are of a different model type.

Comment: @feela i am not saving parent in separate model just to save price related to that particular flight.

Comment: I still don't understand how can I add second child of same parent I search out a lot but confused.

Comment: @mishi Just add another child with the same parent ID. What really is your problem?